# How to change elements on dropdown/slider update in holoviews?

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I would like to update plot elements whenever the user changes a slider/dropdown menu.

I read through the related section in the official [docs](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Custom_Interactivity.html), however I don't see really how my usecase is covered by that.

To make it a bit more concrete: Take this example from the official [website](http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/dropdown_economic.html). Is it possible to update the title of the plot when the dropdown menu changes. Imagine for example that the title gets prefixed with the position of the text element in the dropdown menu (i.e. "1. Austria", "2.Belgium",...). 
How would one achieve that with holoviews?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's practical to achieve using HoloViews alone, but you should be able to do any arbitrary manipulations like that using Panel (panel.pyviz.org).

Comment: Thx, I will have a look at it.